# Is it possible to auto-categorize posts in forums or BBS?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, forum, webbbs

If I have a forum using tags to categorize posts, is it possible to automatically add tags  according to contents and titles after posts are created ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, it is possible if you write code to do it.

Comment: What kind of algorithms should I use ?

Comment: @konforce Congratulations, that's probably the least helpful comment I've ever seen on SO.

Comment: Maybe saying "ANYTHING IS POSSIBLE!" would be less helpful.

Comment: @Nick, that's probably the nicest thing anybody has ever said to me! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to have a table of known tags. Iterate over each word in the post, and if the word is in the tag table add it to the list. To make this slightly more effective, you could store the tag in both its display and stemmed version (e.g., algorithms and algorithm). Then compared the stemmed words in the post with the stemmed tag name. See Porter's stemming algorithm for a simple way to do that (for English words).

A more effective solution would be using something like TF-IDF and associate vectors with each tag. Create a vector for the new post and compare it to each tag vector using cosine similarity. Whichever tags are above a certain threshold would be added to the post. I've never used it for auto-tagging, but in my experience it is a very effective matching tool when dealing with non-spammy data. (i.e., People aren't trying to cheat or fool the system.)

Both of these methods assume that you already have some sort of tag dictionary built to start things off. You could guess at tag names by looking at which uncommon words (need a frequency table for that) are used frequently in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this auto-tagging PHP code:

http://www.dangrossman.info/2008/04/07/auto-tagging-content-with-open-calais/

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways to go about this. Simple keyword matching or TF-IDF, as konforce suggest, are viable options. Others include:

- Use Yahoo's [term extraction](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/content/V1/termExtraction.html) webservice to extract significant terms from the text.
- Use the [Google Prediction API](http://code.google.com/apis/predict/). Train it on a corpus of already tagged posts, then ask it to predict the tags of new posts.